# AWS S3 static site subdirectory to serve content from ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns

I have a personal static AWS S3 website and I've configured example.com to point to this using DNS and Route 53.

As of recently, I now also have a wordpress blog, which is an ec2 instance. I've created a DNS record to point the subdomain blog.example.com to the ec2 instance.

This all works fine.

However, my research suggests that from a SEO perspective the blog would be better served via a subdirectory as opposed to a subdomain e.g.
example.com/blog/

Is it even possible to do this in S3 using redirect rules or something, and if so how would I go about doing this?

Thankyou

Comment: Did you end up solving this? trying to do the same thing now, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this. You can leverage S3's Routing Rules feature.

Rather than copy-paste their documentation, here is a pointer to the documentation that specifies how you may do this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax